# File-writing program in C on Unix stuck at 508 open/close cycles

Tags: c, unix, fopen, read-write

I've written a program in C to write series of characters to a file -- 5 alphanumerics, followed by one `(char)(30)`, a 'record-delimiter' character, repeat... No newlines.  The program is able to loop flawlessly until it reaches the 508th iteration -- 3048 characters -- and then dies, saying I can't access the file.

The structure of the program necessitates a closing and reopening of the file every time this sequence is written (the script is part of a larger pseudo-database-simulating module), so there are 508 cycles through the open/write/close process... Before I start dissecting the database module code (of which there are quite a few lines, so I'd rather not have to if I can avoid it), I was wondering if anyone knew of a rarely-encountered read/write limit in Unix, or a problem with 3048 characters in a file in under a certain time limit, or a problem with 508 {30}'s in a file, or something simple (but hard to catch) like that.  I tried delaying the read/write by a few ms on the off-chance it was accidentally fopening as it fclosed, or tripping over itself like that, but no cigar.

Comment: Why don't you... show us a minimal sample that exhibits this problem? Chances are you are leaking resources (buffers, filedescriptors, other things)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

508 is suspiciously close to 512, a reasonable default value for the number of open files.  Type the command `ulimit -a` and see what limits are imposed.  On my Fedora 15 system, 1024 is the limit for number of open files per process:

```
[wally@lenovotower ~]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 22084
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

If yours is 512, make sure the program is actually closing the file.  Without showing some code, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Also running `lsof -p pid-of-your-program` should tell you if you're leaking file descriptors (if you have open files that you're never closing).

Comment: or just `find /proc/$PID/fd`. Anyways, this is not a real answer, of course (there isn't a real question IMO)

Comment: *508 is suspiciously close to 512*: Yes, plus stdin, stdout, and stderr gets you all the way to 511. (ie: x < 512) :-)

Comment: @TallJeff:  Yep, adding the program executable (which is an open file during execution) makes it to 512.

Comment: You're absolutely right @wallyk -- the code (the more I use it, the crappier it seems) was fclosing the wrong file each time, and it made it to 508 before deciding it had had it with me and my ridiculous expectations for simultaneously open files.  Fixed it because of your ulimit suggestion -- thank you so much!

EDIT: Incidentally, I valgrind'd all over the place and it didn't catch anything wrong.  Note to future interwebbers who have a similar problem: ulimit it up.